# How get total of High and Low of candle and print it on top and bottom of each candle in Pine Script

Tags: pine-script, pine-script-v5

how to get total of candle HIGH and LOW in Single Digit and plot HIGH/LOW value of candle and Total

i.e. Total of 48306 = 4+8+3+0+6 = 21 = 2+1 = 3

Candle HIGH & Total on top of candle and Candle LOW & Total below for Last 50 Candles

```
//@version=5
indicator("Addition v1", overlay = true, max_labels_count=500)

[dh, dl] = request.security(syminfo.ticker, "D", [high[0], low[0]], lookahead=barmerge.lookahead_on)

h = high
l = low

f_add(_number) =>
    var float sum = 0
    a = str.split(str.replace_all(str.tostring(_number),'.',''),'')
    for i = 0 to array.size(a) - 1
        sum += str.tonumber(array.get(a,i))

dhigh = math.round(h)

f_get_digit(num, digit) =>
    int temp = num
    int ret_val = na

    if (num == 0)
        ret_val := 0
    else
        cnt = 0
        while (temp != 0)
            dig = temp % 10
            temp := int(temp / 10)
            cnt := cnt + 1

            if (cnt == digit)
                ret_val := dig
                break
    ret_val

s = "High: " + str.tostring(dhigh) + "\n"

//Plot Candle High Value
if (barstate.islast)
    label.new(bar_index, high, s, textcolor=color.white, textalign=text.align_left)
    
//Plot Candle High Value Total
if (barstate.islast)
    label.new(bar_index, high, str.tostring(f_add(dhigh)), textcolor=color.white)
```

[image]

Comment: i cant imagine why anybody would want this. Is it simply proof of concept?

Comment: Thanks a lot but how do I add this 21 as 2+1 =3 as total

Comment: In the question you say you want to plot the total. Do you just want a label of the total?